# Can I use WHERE clause after JOIN USING in snowflake?

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, using

Can I use WHERE after

JOIN USING?

In my case if I run on snowflake multiple times the same code:

```
with CTE1 as
(
select * 
from A
left join B 
on A.date_a = B.date_b
)
select * 
from CTE1
inner join C 
using(var1_int)
where CTE1.date_a >= date('2020-10-01')
limit 1000;
```

sometimes I get a result and sometimes i get the error:

```
SQL compilation error: Can not convert parameter 'DATE('2020-10-01')' of type [DATE] into expected type [NUMBER(38,0)]
```

where NUMBER(38,0) is the type of var1_int column

Comment: You totally changed the question after the 1st version after a correct answer. You should roll this back, accept the 1st answer & ask a new question. PS This is not clear. What example are you asking about, and what is your question about it? Please edit to give 1 query. The 1st code block with A & B has no [mre]. Of course the 2nd block returns a.date_1. Find the first point in the evaluation that doesn't return what you expect. Give that code. Say what you expect & why you expect it with justification from the manual. You still haven't given a [mre] for it because you haven't done that.

Comment: You should first check the relational schemas in the database.
Then you have to look at which column is the primary key which column is the foreign key.
After checking them, you can join more efficiently.
Finally, I see that the date type is number. You need to edit it according to the data type.
I suggest you try again after applying these.

Comment: the answer was not solving the problem and as said: the second block returns b.date_1 instead of a.

Comment: That was not your question at the time of the first answer, you asked about an error & the answer answered it & also solved it & questions should not be changed in a way that invalidates reasonable answers. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the existence of a `where` clause.  Of course you can use a `where` clause after `join`s.  That is how SQL queries are constructed.

According to the error message, `CTE1.date_a` is a number.  Comparing it to a date results in a type-conversion error.  If you provided sample data and desired results, then it might be possible to suggest a way to fix the problem.

Comment: CTE1.date_a is a date. As mentioned, the  query sometimes works and sometimes throws the error
maybe it is connected to using USING after ON

Comment: I managed to rebuild the question with you hint, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: Instead of `JOIN .. USING()` always prefer `JOIN .. ON`.

---

You are right to be suspicious of the results. Given your staging, only one of these queries returns without errors:

```sql
select a.date_1, id_1
from AE_USING_TST_A a
left join AE_USING_TST_B b 
on a.date_1 = b.date_2
join AE_USING_TST_C v
using(id_1)
where A.date_1 >= date('2020-10-01')

-- Can not convert parameter 'DATE('2020-10-01')' of type 
-- [DATE] into expected type [NUMBER(38,0)]
;


select a.date_1, a.id_1
from AE_USING_TST_A a
left join AE_USING_TST_B b 
on a.date_1 = b.date_2
join AE_USING_TST_C v
on a.id_1=v.id_1
where A.date_1 >= date('2020-10-01')

-- 2020-10-11   2
;
```

I would call this a bug, except that the documentation is clear about not doing this kind of queries with `JOIN .. USING`:

> To use the USING clause properly, the projection list (the list of columns and other expressions after the SELECT keyword) should be “*”. This allows the server to return the key_column exactly once, which is the standard way to use the USING clause. For examples of standard and non-standard usage, see the examples below.
>
> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join.html

The documentation doubles down on the problems of using `USING()` on non-standard situations, with a different query acting "wrong":

> The following example shows non-standard usage; the projection list contains something other than “*”. Because the usage is non-standard, the output contains two columns named “userid”, and the second occurrence (which you might expect to contain a value from table ‘r’) contains a value that is not in the table (the value ‘a’ is not in the table ‘r’).

So just prefer `JOIN .. ON`. For extra discussion on the SQL ANSI standard not defining behavior for some cases of `USING()` check:

- https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008WRZBBSA5/bug-with-join-using-

Comment: What standard SQL disallows is dotting a using column; there's only one copy of it in the join result. And the question code doesn't violate that. The quoted documentation is wrong that only \* is allowed by the standard. If it's not supported, that's non-standard behaviour. PS I notice you're from Snowflake.

Comment: See my comment on the question. The question is muddled. The question's 1st code block & its error message is a different problem than the problem in its 2nd code block. The 1st doesn't give a [mre] & the types of its columns are not all the same as the corresponding columns in the 2nd. Your 1st changes the table names from their 1st to those of their 2nd but doesn't produce the error you claim it does using the tables of the question's 2nd code block. What are you trying to say about either of their 1st or your 1st? What exactly does your 1st have to do with either of theirs?

Comment: But what is the question @philipxy? I agree that there is an error, and I'm glad that the question was able to provide a reproducible example. The issue is solved by not doing `USING` but `ON` for a `JOIN`. Note that I used only the staging from the second part, and then added the `WHERE` statement to recreate the error. What else can I do to be helpful here?

Comment: What do you mean, what is the question? The OP's, or mine? Why can't you address mine--what is your 1st query doing in your post?---It isn't quite the question post's 1st query (which is essentially irrelevant to the 2nd part & was answered by an answer before the 2nd query was edited in) & it doesn't produce the error you give when run with the 2nd question's initialization. Also the 2nd question query doesn't dot incorrectly, as your 2nd example & your community link do, so those 2 things are irrelevant. Although it selects on other than \*, so the documentation \* quote is relevant.

Comment: Hi @philipxy - hopefully my answer was useful to OP. Let's continue our conversation in a new question if we need to dig deeper. Happy holidays!